# setting vertical spacing between text in html

Tags: html, css

I have some heading one after other on each line. Now i want to make sure that the vertical space between headings is x pixels between heading 1 and heading 2 , and y pixcles between heading 3 and 4. How can i ensure it?

Answer (score 2):

Add some `margin-bottom` to heading 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

**html:**

```
<h1>Heading One</h1>
<h2>Heading Two</h2>
<h3>Heading Three</h3>
<h4>Heading Four</h4>
```

**css:**

```
h1 {
   margin-bottom: Xpx;
}

h3 {
   margin-bottom: Ypx
}
```

Comment: @thirtydot - I changed your ?? variables back to x and y as I think they make more sense given they specifically mentioned in the original question. Thanks for correcting the px spelling.
OP - I'm assuming you know to change the x and y values to numbers.

Comment: No problem, I probably shouldn't have changed that. It just looked confusing to have `x` and `y` (which usually refer to horizontal and vertical both as part of `margin-bottom` which is purely vertical). Also, he might get confused and leave the space in there, which would be wrong (he might put `9 px`).

Comment: All true. If the OP hadn't named them as X and Y it wouldn't be such a good idea. I've corrected the spaces.

Answer (score -1):

use style for it,

1) For first header like

```
<h1 style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">First Header</h1>
<h1 style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">Second Header</h1>
```